# AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'to_cpu'

Tags: numpy, chainer, cupy

Good day,

I'm developing a deep learning model for wireless signal detection. Below is the snippet of the function that computes the model accuracy and bit error rate (BER):

```
from chainer.datasets import TupleDataset
import numpy as np
from chainer import cuda
from chainer import function

def get_idp_acc(model, dataset_tuple, comp_ratio, profile = None, batchsize = 128, gpu = -1):
    chainer.config.train = True
    xp = np if gpu < 0 else cuda.cupy
    x, indices, x_zf, HtH, Hty = dataset_tuple._datasets[0], dataset_tuple._datasets[1], dataset_tuple._datasets[2], dataset_tuple._datasets[3], dataset_tuple._datasets[4]

    accs = 0
    BERs = 0
    model.train = False

    for j in range(0, len(x), batchsize):
        x_batch = xp.array(x[j:j + batchsize])
        indices_batch = xp.array(indices[j:j + batchsize])
        x_zf_batch = xp.array(x_zf[j:j + batchsize])
        HtH_batch = xp.array(HtH[j:j + batchsize])
        Hty_batch = xp.array(Hty[j:j + batchsize])
        if profile == None:
            acc_data = model(x_batch, indices_batch, x_zf_batch, HtH_batch, Hty_batch, comp_ratio = comp_ratio,
                            ret_param = 'acc')
        else:
            acc_data = model(x_batch, indices_batch, x_zf_batch, HtH_batch, Hty_batch, comp_ratio = comp_ratio,
                            ret_param = 'acc', profile = profile)

        acc_data.to_cpu()
        acc = acc_data.data
        BER = 1.0 - acc
        accs += acc * len(x_batch)
        BERs += BER * len(x_batch)
    return (accs / len(x)) * 100.
```

When the code is run, I get the following error below despite having imported all the required chainer modules. I really need your help on this issue as I'm stuck for nearly two months without making any headways in my project.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/run_mlp.py", line 14, in <module>
    mlp.run(args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/mlp.py", line 39, in run
    acc_dict[name], BER_dict[name] = util.sweep_idp(model, test, comp_ratios, args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/util.py", line 107, in sweep_idp
    batchsize=args.batchsize, profile=profile))
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/util.py", line 83, in get_idp_acc
    acc_data.to_cpu()
AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'to_cpu'
```

Below is the additional information providing codes for model definition:

```
K = 10
num_layers = 3*K

def lin_soft_sign(x, t):
    '''Linear soft sign activation function from the original paper Eq. (11)'''
    y =  -1 + F.relu(x + t)/ F.absolute(t) - F.relu(- t)/ F.absolute(t)
    return y

def accuracy(x, y):
    '''Computes the fraction of elements for which x and y are equal'''
    return np.mean(np.equal(x, y)).astype(np.float32)


class MLP(chainer.Chain):
    def __init__(self, K, coeff_generator, profiles = None, z_dims = 8*K, v_dims = 2*K):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        if profiles == None:
            profiles = [(0, 10)]
        self.coeff_generator = coeff_generator
        self.z_dims = z_dims
        self.v_dims = v_dims
        self.K = K
        self.profiles = profiles
        self.profile = 0
        with self.init_scope():
            self.p0_l1 = IncompleteLinear(None, self.z_dims)
            self.p1_l1 = IncompleteLinear(None, self.z_dims)
            self.p2_l1 = IncompleteLinear(None, self.z_dims)
            self.p0_lv = IncompleteLinear(None, self.v_dims)
            self.p1_lv = IncompleteLinear(None, self.v_dims)
            self.p2_lv = IncompleteLinear(None, self.v_dims)
            self.p0_l3 = IncompleteLinear(None, self.K)
            self.p1_l3 = IncompleteLinear(None, self.K)
            self.p2_l3 = IncompleteLinear(None, self.K)

    def __call__(self, x, indices, x_zf, HtH, Hty, ret_param = 'loss', profile = None, comp_ratio = None):
        if profile == None:
            profile = self.profile

        # Form Zero-forcing detection
        err_rel = F.sum((x - x_zf)**2, axis = 1) 

        params = layer_profile(self.coeff_generator,
                               *self.profiles[profile], self.z_dims,
                               self.v_dims, comp_ratio)

        def detnet_layer(x_d, x_logit, v, z_dims, v_dims):

            HtH_x = np.matmul(HtH, np.expand_dims(x_d.data, axis = 2).astype(np.float32))
            HtH_x = F.squeeze(HtH_x, axis = -1)

            #x_concat = np.concatenate([Hty, x, HtH_x, v], axis=1)
            x_concat = F.concat([Hty, x_d, HtH_x, v], axis = 1)

            if profile == 0:
                z = F.relu(self.p0_l1(x_concat))
                v += self.p0_lv(z, *params)
                x_logit += self.p0_l3(z, *params)
                x = lin_soft_sign(x_logit, F.broadcast_to(np.ones(1).astype(np.float32), x_logit.shape))

            elif profile == 1:
                z = F.relu(self.p1_l1(x_concat))
                v += self.p1_lv(z, *params)
                x_logit += self.p1_l3(z, *params)
                x = lin_soft_sign(x_logit, F.broadcast_to(np.ones(1).astype(np.float32), x_logit.shape))
            elif profile == 2:
                z = F.relu(self.p2_l1(x_concat))
                v += self.p2_lv(z, *params)
                x_logit += self.p2_l3(z, *params)
                x = lin_soft_sign(x_logit, F.broadcast_to(np.ones(1).astype(np.float32), x_logit.shape))

            return x, x_logit, v

        x_k = np.zeros((Hty.shape[0], self.K), dtype = np.float32)
        x_k_logit = np.zeros((Hty.shape[0], self.K), dtype = np.float32)
        v = np.zeros((Hty.shape[0], self.v_dims), dtype = np.float32)
        loss = 0

        mod = sg.Modulator('BPSK', K)

        for k in range(1, num_layers + 1):

            x_k, x_k_logit, v = detnet_layer(x_k, x_k_logit, v, self.z_dims, self.v_dims)
            err = F.sum((x - x_k)**2, 1) 
            loss += (np.log(k)).astype(np.float32) * F.mean(err/err_rel)       

        report = {'loss': loss, 'acc': accuracy(mod.demodulate(x_k.data), indices)}

        reporter.report(report, self)
        return report[ret_param]

    def report_params(self):
        return ['validation/main/acc']

    def param_names(self):
        if len(self.profiles) > 1:
            return 'IDPDETNET_{}_{}_{}_p{}'.format(self.z_dims, self.v_dims, self.coeff_generator.__name__, len(self.profiles))
        return 'IDPDETNET_{}_{}_{}'.format(self.z_dims, self.v_dims, self.coeff_generator.__name__) 

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import numpy as np

import visualize as vz
import idp.coeffs_generator as cg
from net import MLP
import util
K = 10
N = 4
v_dims = 2*K
z_dims = 8*K
SNR_dB_tmin = -4
SNR_dB_tmax = 24

SNR_dB_test = np.linspace(SNR_dB_tmin, SNR_dB_tmax, 8)
num_snr_test = len(SNR_dB_test)

def run(args):
    train, test = util.get_dataset(args.modeltype)
    names = ['all-one (standard)', 'linear']
    colors = [vz.colors.all_one_lg, vz.colors.linear_lg]
    models = [
                MLP.MLP(K, cg.uniform, z_dims = 8*K, v_dims = 2*K),
                MLP.MLP(K, cg.linear, z_dims = 8*K, v_dims = 2*K)
                ]

    comp_ratios = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 20)
    acc_dict = {}
    BER_dict = {}
    ratios_dict = {}

    for i in range(num_snr_test):
        for name, model in zip(names, models):
            util.load_or_train_model(model, train, test, args)
            acc_dict[name], BER_dict[name] = util.sweep_idp(model, test, comp_ratios, args)
            ratios_dict[name] = [100. * cr for cr in comp_ratios]

    filename = "IDPDETNET1_{}".format(args.modeltype)
    vz.plot(ratios_dict, acc_dict, names, filename, colors = colors,
            folder = args.figure_path, ext=args.ext,
            title = 'IDPDETNET (BPSK)',
            xlabel = 'IDP (%)',
            ylabel = 'Test Accuracy (%)', ylim = (0, 100))

    filename = "IDPDETNET2_{}".format(args.modeltype)
    vz.plot(ratios_dict, BER_dict, names, filename, colors = colors,
            folder=args.figure_path, ext=args.ext,
            title='IDPDETNET (BPSK)',
            xlabel='IDP (%)',
            ylabel='BER (bits/sec)')

    filename = "IDPDETNET3_{}".format(args.modeltype)
    vz.plot(num_snr_test,   BER_dict, names, filename, colors = colors,
        folder = args.figure_path, ext = args.ext,
        title = 'IDPDETNET (BPSK)',
        xlabel = 'SNR (dB)',
        ylabel = ' BER (bits/sec)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = util.default_parser('IDPDETNET Example').parse_args()
    run(args)
```

Hi Seiya Tokui. Thank you for your kind input. Here is the model definition based on the above code:

```
model = MLP.MLP(K, cg.uniform, z_dims = 8*K, v_dims = 2*K)
```

OR

```
model = MLP.MLP(K, cg.linear, z_dims = 8*K, v_dims = 2*K)
```

Hi @BloodyD. Thank for your brilliant contributions. The model started training, but then later returned the following error:

```
1           nan         nan                   0.50108              5.85448
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_mlp.py", line 14, in <module>
    mlp.run(args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/mlp.py", line 38, in run
    util.load_or_train_model(model, train, test, args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/util.py", line 204, in load_or_train_model
    train_model(model, train, test, args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/idp_detnet/examples/util.py", line 184, in train_model
    return eval(fp.read().replace('\n', ''))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NaN' is not defined
```

The error occurs in the last line of this snippet code below:

```
name = model.param_names()
    save_model(model, os.path.join(args.model_path, name))
    chainer.config.train = False
    with open(os.path.join(args.out, 'log'), 'r') as fp:
        return eval(fp.read().replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: Would you share the definition of `model`? It looks `model(...)` returns a `numpy.ndarray` object (not `chainer.Variable`), which causes the error.

Comment: Try to use `acc_data = cuda.to_cpu(acc_data)`. It more generic and is independent whether it is a `chainer.Variable`, `cupy.ndaray` or `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Furthermore, you use `numpy` in order to compute the accuracy, which already returns an object/number located on the CPU. If you want, you can extend your `accuracy` function with an `xp` parameter and pass this parameter as following: `accuracy(mod.demodulate(x_k.data), indices, xp=self.xp)`. More specific, `chainer.Chain.xp()` attribute returns either `numpy` or `cupy` moduled, depending on either your model is located on the GPU or CPU.

Comment: Thank you very much @BloodyD for your wonderful input. After effecting the changes, the model started training, but then later return into another error "NAN" not defined.

Comment: hmm... Firstly, I don't really get the necessity of the `eval(fp.read().replace('\n', ''))` part. In python `eval` interprets a string as python code and evaluates it. In your case, you are reading the final log file and try to execute the content of the log file in python. Do you really want it? Second, it looks like your training diverged since I see `nan` values in your print report. Divergence of the training may have several causes: too high learning rate, mathematically instable computations, or you forgot to clear the gradients of your model before training start (`model.cleargrads()`)